# Is it possible to make guacamole without acid?

Tags: substitutions, acidity

All guacamole recipes call for lime juice, some tomato variant, even hot sauce. I want to make a low-acid guacamole.

Is the acid necessary? How do I go about making low-acid guacamole? If it plays a role in the finished product, is there something I can substitute?

Comment: Hello Sonihal, recipe requests are off topic here. I rewrote your question to be more general, instead of closing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At its simplest, guacamole is just mashed avocado. Avocado is not particularly acidic on its own, so add whatever non-acidic ingredients you like.

Consider cilantro, sour cream or whatever low or non-acid flavorings suit you.

See: [Browning Avocados - What Helps?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/46494/browning-avocados-what-helps) for more on acid and avocados.

Comment: That said, depending on what the reason is for avoiding acid, the recipes with acidic ingredients might be fine. It's generally a pretty small amount, more on the scale of brightening the flavor than making it tangy.

Comment: Simple guac with just salt and pepper is great. :)

Comment: @Catija Don't forget the vitamin C! :)

Answer (score 1):

Acidity helps the avocado/guac stay fresh, without acidity it oxidizes fast & it turns brown.