# How do I tone down onion sharpness already in the chicken salad?

Tags: chicken, flavor, onions, salad

How do I tone down onion sharpness already in the chicken salad?  It asked for red onion, which I didn't have so I used the only thing I had, shallot.  I used far less than indicated.  I have already added an avocado and a packet of stevia to the chicken salad but it is still too oniony for my taste.

Comment: I keep a backup of dehydrated minced onion in the pantry for these occasions. I'm pretty impressed you had shallot handy.

Answer (score 1):

As much vinegar as the salad will take *might* help a bit. Salt too, but your window there will be even narrower. Obviously, too much of either of those ingredients will ruin the salad.

Basically, I'm hoping for a bit of a 'pickling' effect. Onions become dramatically less sharp after even the briefest of pickling. So I'm hopeful that a reasonable amount of extra salt and vinegar plus time will help.

Of course, making a bigger salad by adding more of everything else is your safest option, but I'm sure you have already thought of that. Also, time alone will help some.

Comment: Would you use balsamic vinegar, white wine, apple cider?  And how much do you think?  1 TBSP?  It has only 5 TBSP of greek yogurt, and a pound of cubed chicken, 1 granny smith apple, 1.5 c grapes, 2 oz. almonds, 1 c celery, 1/4 c shallot, 1 t ground ginger.  Plus the 1 avocado and 1 pkt stevia.

Comment: @MarieAnders  I first thought white wine vinegar when I saw your question, but then after reading your recipe I think apple cider would also be a good choice. I'd avoid balsamic because it will add a lot of color and you already have added sweetness. As far as amount, do it by the half tablespoon, tasting after each mix. Use as much as you can without it being too much, and understand that it will probably take an hour for it to work (if it does work).

Comment: @MarieAnders BTW read both of my answers here: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/46494/browning-avocados-what-helps If you add vinegar, you might want to add some Vitamin C too to prevent it from causing your avocado to badly brown.

Comment: Please come back and let us know how it goes! You might want to uncheck the accept box for now because others might have good advice too. However, the accept check and a comment would be great if the advice works for you. OH, and welcome to Seasoned Advice! Good first question.

Comment: There is a concentrated herbed vinegar called Gurkenmeister available at most delis. It is my go-to for fixing savory dishes, and I never let my kitchen run out of it. If you don't have extra chicken to put into the salad, a teaspoon of this stuff should go a long way toward toning down the onion taste.