# How can I preserve avocados longer?

Tags: avocados

Avocados are tricky beasts.  If you get them while the peel's still green, they're hard as stones.  When they ripen, the skin goes brown and the flesh softens, but when this happens you have to eat them **immediately** or they'll start to go bad right away, often ending up full of nasty brown spots within a day or two.

Is there any (relatively simple) way to keep them ripe and still edible for a bit longer?

(In case it makes any difference, I'm talking about ordinary Hass avocados you can buy in pretty much any normal supermarket in the US.)

Comment: Related, this _tour de force_: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/46494/browning-avocados-what-helps/46495#46495

Comment: @ElendilTheTall Just to be clear, I'm thinking of intact, unpeeled avocados. That question's about cutting them up and preserving the flesh afterwards.

Comment: That's why I said related, not duplicate :) Have you tried simply freezing them?

Answer (score 6):

I haven't done a side-by-side comparison, but I find that once an avocado's ripe, I can keep it there for a few days by putting it in the fridge.

It doesn't halt the process of getting brown spots inside, but it seems to slow it down some.

Comment: ...where "some" is "quite a bit", particularly if you don't wait too long.

Comment: @Ecnerwal : a few days is fine.  I did it once, and realized about two weeks later, and there were some brown spots.  It wasn't totally scary inside and was mostly green, but wasn't all green.  That one might've been a special case, as I think I had it in a 80 to 90°F room before fridging it.